# Two JSON objects are returned when INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR is handled by RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, internal-server-error

Consider the following code:

**MyRestController:**

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    @GetMapping("/whiteLabelError")
    public StreamingResponseBody whiteLabelError() {
        return out -> {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        };
    }
}
```

**MyRestControllerAdvice**

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyRestControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {RuntimeException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleRestRuntimeException(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, new HttpHeaders(), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```

The response is the following:

```
   "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"{
        "timestamp": "2021-04-23T13:51:41.438+0000",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "message": "I throw a RuntimeException",
        "path": "/response"
    }
```

I would expect to return only the first object:
"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"

I found in the ResonseEntityExceptionHandler Spring's class the following, but I don't know if this affects the response body:

```
if (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(status)) {
    request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE, ex, WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
}
```

Does anybody know why this code returns two JSON objects?

Comment: looks like the response JSON is not at all a valid one

Comment: It seems almost as if the request was written to twice...

Comment: The first JSON is the one returned by my code. The second one is the default Spring response. I am interested why the Spring concatenates the default response after my custom response.

Comment: I think I found the source of this behavior: [spring-framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java#L111). The custom exception is added to the Spring's default WhiteLabel Error Message.